# Remove Linked List Elements -pascal

Tags: pascal, singly-linked-list

I have a problem with `prosedeur supression()` when inserting an `etudent` (more than one) and deleted by suprrision Procedure and make a search about that item I delete the program and I guess the problem is in ? prosedur supression()`. Look at it first.

I wish that clear thank u guys now

```
 declartion to types student and moudle and note
 Program liste_des_etudiants;
    Type 
        date = Record
            jour,mois,anee : Integer;
        End;
        ptr_etu = ^etudiant;
        etudiant = Record
            matricule : String;
            nom,prenom,adress : String;
            date_n : date;
            suiv : ptr_etu;
        End;
        ptr_mod = ^module;
        module = Record
            code,libelle : String;
            credit,coeff : Integer;
            suiv : ptr_mod;
        End;
        ptr_note = ^note;
        note = Record
            matricule : String;
            code : String;
            note : Integer;
            suiv : ptr_note;
        End;
    Var 
        choix : String;
        liste_etudiant : ptr_etu ;
        liste_note : ptr_note;
        liste_module : ptr_mod;
```

Procedure supression etudent

```
Procedure supression(Var etu:ptr_etu;module:ptr_mod;note:ptr_note );
var
  choix,matr,code : String;
  current,prvious,Next: ptr_etu;
  current_note,privous_note :ptr_note;
  privous_code,current_code: ptr_mod;
begin
  Repeat
    Repeat
      Writeln('pour supression un etudiant tapez 1');
      Writeln('pour supression un note tapez 2');
      Writeln('pour supression un module tapez 3');
      Writeln('pour sortir tapez e ');
      Readln(choix);
    Until ((choix='1') Or (choix='2') Or (choix='3') Or (choix='e') Or (choix='E'));

    If (choix='1') Then
    Begin
      // I guess the porblem is here but i don't know is it 
      // initcation de node 
      current := etu ;
      Writeln('donner son matricule') ;
      Readln(matr);
      // traitement to the if the node we wanna delet is the 
      // first one
      While((etu<>Nil) And(etu^.matricule=matr))Do
        etu:= etu^.suiv;
      While ((current<>Nil) and (current^.suiv<>nil)) Do
      Begin
        next:=etu^.suiv;
        if (next^.matricule=matr) then
        begin
          current^.suiv:=next^.suiv;
        end
        Else
          current:=current^.suiv;
      end;
             
      if (current =nil) then
        writeln('l ''''etudiant n''''est pas trouvee');

  Until ((choix='e') Or(choix='E'));
end;
```

Main

```
Begin
  Repeat
    Repeat
      Writeln('tapez:');
      Writeln('1):pour insertion');
      Writeln('2):pour modification');
      Writeln('3):pour supression');
      Writeln('4):pour recherche');
      Writeln('(e)pour sortir');
      Readln(choix);
    Until ((choix='1') Or (choix='2') Or (choix='3') Or (choix='4') Or (choix='e'));

    If (choix='1') Then
      insertion(liste_etudiant, liste_module,liste_note)
    Else If (choix='2') Then
      modification(liste_etudiant, liste_module,liste_note)
    Else If (choix='3') Then
      supression(liste_etudiant,liste_module,liste_note)
    Else if (choix='4') Then
      recherche(liste_etudiant, liste_module,liste_note)

  Until ((choix='e') Or (choix='E'));
End.
```

Comment: Please edit your question and use e.g., Google Translate to help you write meaningful sentences in English. Also, show the node structure, and the complete procedure / function that you are having problems with, together with declarations of any variable, constant or other identifier that your code includes. If you are getting error messages, indicate the exact line where that error occurs, and the error message.

Comment: i reformaing my code and I add everything u just told i hope that clear

Comment: I reformatted your code to make it readable. Please note, that programming in general requires discipline, accuracy and focus to details. It is crucial to follow the editing standards for the programming language you are working with. I also removed the repeated texts about the problem you have. Please don't vast space in your message and the readers time with sloppy and careless editing.

Comment: Pay attention to the pairs of `begin`- `end` in "Procedure supression etudent"